# How to create an OVS Bridge in centos (Openstack) ipv6 interface

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, openstack

I am trying to create an ovs bridge network for openstack(packstack) . I am encountering an issue as per documentation i need to create interface as shown below.

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br-ex

```
DEVICE=br-ex
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.122.212 # Old eth0 IP since we want the network restart to not 
                       # kill the connection, otherwise pick something outside your dhcp range
NETMASK=255.255.255.0  # your netmask
GATEWAY=192.168.122.1  # your gateway
DNS1=192.168.122.1     # your nameserver
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=OVSPort
DEVICETYPE=ovs
OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex
ONBOOT=yes
```

Existing configuration in hetzner is as follows:

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=hardware address
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=<public ip>
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
SCOPE="peer <gateway ip>"
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=<ipv6 address>/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/router-eth0

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH - installimage
# routing for eth0
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=<gateway ip>
```

How to configure br-ex(OVS bridge) in hetzner server where eth0(ipv6) interface gateway is mentioned in route-eth0?